# laravel 5.4 many to many relationship

Tags: database, laravel, relationship

i have relationship many to many table 'admins' , 'pjt_roles' with pjt_role_admin.
but,not working

i have 2 model

class Role

```
protected $table = 'pjt_roles';

public function Admin(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Admin::class',pjt_role_admin');
}
```

class Admin

```
public function Role(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'pjt_role_admin');
}
```

and table `pjt_role_admin` have attribute

1. admin_id from table `admins`
2. role_id from table `pjt_roles`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your pivot table in relationship. Default laravel assume `admin_role` as your pivot table because you have `Admin` and `Role` models

> class Role

```
protected $table = 'pjt_roles';

public function Admin(){ // should be admins() for better readability
    return $this->belongsToMany(Admin::class, 'pjt_role_admin');
}
```

> class Admin

```
public function Role(){ // should be roles() for better readability
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'pjt_role_admin');
}
```

> To determine the table name of the
>   relationship's joining table, Eloquent will join the two related model
>   names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this
>   convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the
>   belongsToMany method.

## Fetch Data

```
$admin = Admin::find(1);
$roles = $admin->Role; // should change to roles() in relationship for better readability
```

## Save

```
$admin->Role()->attach($roleId);
```

details https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: what are you trying to do so it is not working, can you update your question with conteoller code

Comment: i mean controller code, that you are trying to fetch or store using ManyToMany relation

Comment: @storyks i have updated answer for fetch data and save data. check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174004/discussion-between-rkj-and-story-ks).