# How to create many-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```php
// the ticket migration 
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('body');
    $table->timestamps();
});

// ticket and status 
Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('ticket_status', function (Blueprint $table) {    
    $table->integer('ticket_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
    $table->primary(['ticket_id','status_id']);    
});

// store method
public function store()
{   
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required |min:5'
    ]);

    auth()
        ->user()
        ->tickets()
        ->create(request(['title','body','group','status','priority']));

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I have migration for my tickets and I have to get `status_id` and `ticket_id`.

When I use `create` method in my controller `table status_ticket` do not fill with data.

I do not have an error but my table is empty.

Comment: You store method doesn't accept request.
it should be like this
public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $this->validate(request(),[
          'title'=>'required',
          'body'=>'required |min:5'
        ]);

       auth()
             ->user()
             ->tickets()
             ->create(request(['title','body','group','status','priority']));
   
        return redirect('/');

    
    }

Comment: do you have created relationship between `tickets` and `statuses` ?

Comment: check this it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094443/laravel-5-4-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0):

Try to use save, not create. Then the model should be attached

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the methods `belongsTo()` and `hasMany()` in your new models?

If not, you have to add these and then [you can easily save relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).